# WordPress Backend Show Posts with specific number of comments

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wp-admin

I created a function which displays posts with specific number of comments.

```
function wpse45436_posts_filter( $query ) {

    global $post_type, $pagenow; 
    if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'post') {

        if (isset($_GET['reviews'])) {

            $reviews_number = sanitize_text_field($_GET['reviews']);
            $query->query_vars['comment_count']['value'] = $reviews_number;
            $query->query_vars['comment_count']['compare'] = '>=';
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse45436_posts_filter');
```

The code above gets a review number of 100 for example and then shows posts which have more than 100 comments.

However, I want to show posts between 100 and 150 comments for example. So, Is there any way I can add `AND` in the above code to define show posts with  comments number?

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```
$query->query_vars['comment_count']['value'] = [100,150];
$query->query_vars['comment_count']['compare'] = 'BETWEEN';
```

BETWEEN is standard MySQL operator.

Comment: I have checked WP_Query and for comment count it doesn't allow "BETWEEN"